# Debian 11 how to Install GNOME after Install by bootstick

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

I made a mistake during the installation of Debian 11. My plan was to run Debian next to Win10 by using Grub2 but installed Debian high secure LVM which overwrote my notebook's complete Harddisk. I am completely new to Linux so as you can imagine I struggle hard because I only have a "DOS-style-Terminal". The Debian 11 .iso ist only 3xx mb large and I wonder if i am able to install Gnome from the given Terminal. Some sources mentioned Gnome could be part of the .iso .Is it true? Do I have a chance to process? If not I concidered to add a folder on the bootable USB stick, add something like "gnome.deb" and try to progress this way. I dont have internet in my Asus Vivobook model M712D because of missing"RTW88......" which makes my situation even worse but can access the internet by my Smartphone. In the end I want to install vscode to progress at [www.freecodecamp.org](http://www.freecodecamp.org) using Debian instead of Kali for advanced Linux learning and future operations. I am sure this is a topic to discuss, I cant imagine I am the only one struggling on this issue. Many Windows user gets prevented from using linux by this issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small size of the image indicates that you probably used the Network Install image. This minimal image does not feature desktop environments. Your options are:

1. Download an image that features a desktop environment (complete installation image, see [here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/index.en.html)) and reinstall Debian using this image.
2. Install the desktop environment yourself. To do that, you could try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install task-gnome-desktop`. This, however requires an internet connection.

Comment: Please don't encourage off-topic posts. Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions.

Comment: @tripleee Oups, you are right. https://superuser.com/ would be a better place for this question.